# Which is a better way/method to implement and display new comments alert?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So far i have `@comments.count` which gives me the number of all comments in the table,but i need another column which will act as a `previous_count` to compare with `@comments.count` ,   and then do something like this on the view.

```
     if @comments.count is greater than previous_recorded
        display NEW COMMENT
```

My question is how to record and save @comments.count in previous_count?I have thought of using session but i am not sure if that could be safe.Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a datetime instead of a count. A count will be faulty if, say, earlier comments are deleted and then more are added. If you just store the previous datetime (instead of the count) then you can call `@comments.where(:created_at > prev_datetime).count` to get the count. As for storing the "last datetime" a session would be a fine place for that unless you want it to persist across devices, in which case you'd want to save it as an attribute on e.g. your User model.

Answer (score 1):

Might make more sense to look at the timestamps (`created_at` most likely) rather than the counts. Then each client could track the last timestamp they had and just ask for the comments newer than that as needed. This way you wouldn't have to store anything new or worry about different clients having different `previous_count` values, you could just keep track of a timestamp in the session or client-side JavaScript or whatever was convenient.